# Sticky footer, without using position:fixed (always at bottom, minimum height)

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-router

This should be easy and has been answered 100 times, but for some reason it's not working in my code.

I want to have my footer always be at the bottom of the page, but for cases when the content doesn't fill up the full page, it should still sit at the bottom (eg: not always fixed at bottom:0)

HTML

```
<div class="home-wrapper">
    <div ui-view="nav@home"></div>
    <div ui-view="content@{{$state.current.name}}" class="content-div"></div>
    <div ui-view="footer@home" class="footer-bar"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.home-wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.footer-bar {
    height: 3em;
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

I thought by setting the min-height on the home-wrapper we'd have no issues... it works fine when the content area is large, but on elsewise it's shoved right up at the top of the page! I suspect this might be related to the fact that I'm using AngularJS with UI-Router for state routing, and my CSS is loaded on a per-page basis.

You can see a live example up at: http://letsdolunch-web-dev.azurewebsites.net/, click the Legal link at the bottom to see the issue present itself, http://letsdolunch-web-dev.azurewebsites.net/#/legal

Comment: You might find [Ryan Fait's sticky footer helpful](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/). Other concepts with varying degrees of browser compatibility are [here](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/), [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/), and [here](http://mystrd.at/modern-clean-css-sticky-footer/).

Comment: are you opposed to javascript handling the height of the wrapper? height:100% doesn't do what you may think it is doing here

Comment: @KaiQing I'd be fine using javascript, but what do you mean it's not doing what I think it is?

Comment: I mean that min-height:100% looks here like you assume the wrapper will consume the height of its parent, which is defined at 100%. You're probably seeing the footer resting just under the content no matter how much there is so it's always going to be at bottom:0 of home-wrapper, which may not fill the screen even though it is told to have a min-height of 100%...

Comment: I don't know angular too well, but the basic idea is on load you set a resize listener and force the wrapper's min-height to be the screen height minus the header. Fire that resize call on load and it should automatically adjust. I have to do this all the time using jquery.

Comment: All of the HTML and CSS linked by @showdev (and others I've found around) either don't work or break everything else :( This should be easy! I'm not in love with the idea of javascript for every resize but it looks like that's the answer. Thanks all

Comment: If you're interested in troubleshooting, please edit your question to show how you've implemented code that was referenced and demonstrate what specifically goes wrong.